# How to Count All Objects of a Database Table in Django?

Tags: django, count, django-orm

I have a model as below, I would like to filter a `user's all work_times` in Table `Work` with Django 2.0.4, thanks in advance for any advice.

```
class Work(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    work_times = models.FloatField(default=1, verbose_name="work times(hours)")
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="works", blank=True)
```

Comment: Its a simple aggregation. please describe what you want

Comment: I think I already said in original post, I would like to filter a user's all work_times in that model

Comment: its too simple aggregation `Work.objects.filter(user=<selected_user>).aggregate(wt=models.Sum('work_time'))['wt']`

Comment: If I knew it how to achieve, I won't ask here, Sir

Comment: @vorujack Thanks Jack, program say models is not defined, do you know the reason?

Comment: import it form django.db  `from django.db import models`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all of them by using:

`all_work = Work.objects.filter(user=sample_user)`

and if you want to know the number of rows in that query you can user:

`all_work_count = Work.objects.filter(user=sample_user).count()`

You can access each item of that query by:

```
for each_work in all_work:
    print(each_work.work_times)
```

**Edit**

By getting all works of a user, you can access the individual work_time from the work instance. However, you can access the work_times this way as well:

`all_work = Work.objects.filter(user=sample_user).values('work_times')`

This will give you only the work_times. But this way, you cannot know what work_time belongs to which work.

**Edit 2**
To get the total time of work, you have two options, the simple and somewhat more complex:

#### Easy one

This is the technically easy solution, but is usable only for very small query size.

```
all_works = Work.objects.filter(user=sample_user)
total_work = 0
for work in all_works:
    total_work += work.work_times
```

#### Complex one

Although this one is much more efficient and is in one line, you might have to play with it a bit to get it right.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

total_works = Work.objects.filter(user=sample_user).aggregate(Sum("work_times"))
```

Comment: hey, I would like to filter a user's all `work_times` in that model, not all works, such as user A had 45 works, but every work has different `work_times`, thank you so all the same

Comment: @Begin2Pip See the comments. If that is not what you want, you have to tell me what you want to do with the work_times or elaborate more about what you have in mind and your purpose.

Comment: Hi, now I got a list of work_times about the user like this `[{'work_times': 1.0}, {'work_times': 2.0}, {'work_times': 3.0}, {'work_times': 2.0}, {'work_times': 1.0}]`, do you know how to count the key of this list and display on front-end pages?

Comment: @Begin2Pip By determining length of the list with `len(name_of_the_list)`.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for help, but I need the value of total work_times `1.0+2.0+3.0+2.0+1.0` with value of `9.0 hours`, not `len(name_of_the_list)` with value of 5, thank you all the same.........

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, you saved my day

Answer (score 2):

count=User.objects.filter(username='username').first().work_set.all().count()

Comment: hey, I would like to filter a user's all `work_times` in that model, not all works, thank you so all the same

Answer (score 1):

You could count them this way if you want to include just those with work_times different from 1...

```
count = User.objects.filter(work__gt=1).count()
```

Or this way to include also those with work_times equal to 1...

```
count = User.objects.filter(work__gt=1).count()
```

And to get the queryset off all Work objects having a user...

```
all_works = Work.objects.filter(user__isnull=False)
```

You can count them from the last query also by adding .count().

Comment: hey, I would like to filter a user's all work_times in that model, not all works, such as user A had 45 works, but every work has different work_times, what I need is user A's all work_times, thank you all the same